# how to print sklearn's log to file?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I use sklearn's Grid Search part to search the best parameters.

I use Grid Search's verbose argument and the log has been printed successfully.

But I find the log can't be written to a file in this way:

```
python3 xx.py 1>log 2>&1
```

It may be resulted by the intensive log and the stdout buffer.
So how can I print the log into a file, in order to catch the process of the Grid Search.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

You should state verbose=true and the following code in your script:

```
import sys

sys.stdout=open("external_file.txt","w")

<YOUR CODE HERE>

sys.stdout.close()
```

All log prints will be written to the text file. Logging in scikit is done by the print statement.